# Android Composable App Crashes When Attempting Load Images on a List for a Food Menu

Tags: android, image, kotlin, crash, android-jetpack-compose

Good day or night to all who read this.

I am presently learning Android development and have run into a snag with a specific part of the course. I already expect the laughs since I'm new, I'm already laughing as I type imagining the reactions. [Reactions to my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZTF.jpg)

The app crashes after following all instructions to the letter. I noticed if I remove or comment out the line of code specific to calling the Food menu images that the app runs fine... but the moment I put the line back it won't run. Please see code snipit in bold below:

```
@Composable
fun LowerPanel(navController: NavHostController, dishes: List<Dish> = listOf()) {
    Column {
        WeeklySpecialCard()
        LazyColumn {
            itemsIndexed(dishes) { _, dish ->
                MenuDish(navController, dish)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun WeeklySpecialCard() {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.weekly_special),
            fontSize = 26.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = LittleLemonColor.charcoal,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MenuDish(navController: NavHostController? = null, dish: Dish) {
    Card(onClick = {
        Log.d("AAA", "Click ${dish.id}")
        navController?.navigate(DishDetails.route + "/${dish.id}")
    }) {
        Row {
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            Column {
                Text(text = dish.name,
                    color = LittleLemonColor.charcoal,
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(text = dish.description,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = LittleLemonColor.green,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(.75f)
                        .padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp))
                Text(text = "${dish.price}",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = LittleLemonColor.green)
            **}
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = dish.imageResource),
                    contentDescription = "",
                    modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(1.dp)))**
        }
    }
    Divider(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp),
        thickness = 1.dp,
        color = LittleLemonColor.yellow
    )
}
```

I am also attaching the DishRepository.kt that the dish coding for each item. I double checked the images as well and they seem stable and compatible.

```
object DishRepository {
    val dishes = listOf(
        Dish(
            1,
            "Greek Salad",
            "The famous greek salad of crispy lettuce, peppers, olives, our Chicago.",
            12.99,
            R.drawable.greeksalad
        ),
        Dish(
            2,
            "Lemon Desert",
            "Traditional homemade Italian Lemon Ricotta Cake.",
            8.99,
            R.drawable.lemondessert
        ),
        Dish(
            3,
            "Bruschetta",
            "Our Bruschetta is made from grilled bread that has been smeared with garlic and seasoned with salt and olive oil.",
            4.99,
            R.drawable.bruschetta
        ),
        Dish(
            4,
            "Grilled Fish",
            "Fish marinated in fresh orange and lemon juice. Grilled with orange and lemon wedges.",
            19.99,
            R.drawable.grilledfish
        ),
        Dish(
            5,
            "Pasta",
            "Penne with fried aubergines, cherry tomatoes, tomato sauce, fresh chilli, garlic, basil & salted ricotta cheese.",
            8.99,
            R.drawable.pasta
        ),
        Dish(
            6,
            "Lasagne",
            "Oven-baked layers of pasta stuffed with Bolognese sauce, béchamel sauce, ham, Parmesan & mozzarella cheese .",
            7.99,
            R.drawable.lasagne
        )
    )

    fun getDish(id: Int) = dishes.firstOrNull { it.id == id }
}

data class Dish(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val description: String,
    val price: Double,
    @DrawableRes val imageResource: Int
)
```

This is the result I should get,[app example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VznrF.png).
I can load the app without error the moment I remove the Image element. But the photos are part of the Menu for obvious reasons :-). Most of this project already had a foundation laid with me being instructed to insert the provided images, modify texts, and modify primary colors along with utilizing other composable elements. Please let me know where I or the foundation of this project went wrong... I would love to use this as a foundation for a personal project for my wife's business(not a restaurant).

Even if I can be given a guide on how else to properly debug or investigate why the Image element causes the app to crash It would be helpful.

Thank you all once again for your time and attention.

Comment: When your app crashes, Android Studio's Logcat window is the first place to look for detailed error messages.

Comment: I'll check that, Thank you so much!